# getting numbers from multiple text boxes (loop) and writing an equation

Tags: javascript

I am wondering why this loop works even when I add extra variables because I am curious. I only expected numbers1 to work in the loop. Sorry I am new to Javascript

Comment: what do you want to get with this code? what is `numbers1`??

Comment: Any code related to your question must be **in** your question, not linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you. If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site. Instead, put the [**minimum** complete example](/help/mcve) in the question. *(I've fixed it for you on this occasion, note how you can use Stack Snippets now instead of jsFiddle.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you don't understand.
The program sums the values in the elements named "s" and "a".

It uses one loop to sum them together at the same time, which is a bad idea: it only works if there are equal number of elements.

Separate the two:

```
function sumElementsByName(name) {
    var texts = document.getElementsByName(name);
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(texts[i].value || 0);       
    }
    return sum;
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var sum_s = sumElementsByName("s");
    var sum_a = sumElementsByName("a");
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum_s + " and " + sum_a;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It works regardless of how many fields you add because you're using `getElementsByName` to get the fields with `name="s"` and `name="a"`, which will find all of the fields with those names regardless of how many there are, and you're using a loop.

Note, though, that your *output* will always only be last pair of results because you're assigning to the `#sum` element's `innerHTML`.